# Is inject the same thing as reduce in ruby?

Tags: ruby, alias, reduce, inject

I saw that they were documented together [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). Are they the same thing? Why does Ruby have so many aliases (such as map/collect for arrays)? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Yes, and it's also called `fold` in many other programming languages and in Mathematics. Ruby aliases a lot in order to be intuitive to programmers with different backgrounds. If you want to use `#length` on an `Array`, you can. If you want to use `#size`, that's fine too!

Comment: If you want to create your own aliases, you may be interested in [alias_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method).

Comment: #length and #count are not equivalent in Ruby. #length and #size are.

Comment: 3.length gives NoMethodError; 3.size returns 4. Obviously 3 isn't an array, but beware of duck typing! (3_000_000_000_000_000.size returns 8 and 3_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000.size returns 20; it seems to be the amount of memory it takes up.)

Comment: hm, I think the current Ruby docs http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce might be better if it just says the same as `inject` so that users don't have to read the two description and try to figure out if they are the same... doesn't this go with the DRY principle?

Comment: @太極者無極而生, good point, I was confused by this just as you prediced

Comment: @Quolonel Questions, #length and #size are aliases, but #count (without any arguments) is, essentially, the same.

Comment: +1 on the documentation had both inject and reduce together with no explanation, would be clearer to say that they are equivalent.  I googled because I was confused and ended up here.

Comment: Err, why? This seems ridiculous

Comment: Is this equivalent to Haskell's foldl?

Answer (score 9):

More recent versions of the documentation of [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) specify it explicitly:

> The `inject` and `reduce` methods are aliases. There is no performance benefit to either.

Comment: i like to separate them based on how it's used, obviously just for semantics. if its a proc (`&:+`), reduce, if it's a block, inject

Answer (score 4):

> Are they the same thing?

Yes, aliases run the exact same code in the end.

> Why does Ruby have so many aliases (such as map/collect for arrays)?

It boils down to the language's approach

Different languages have different approaches, I tried to [visualize it here](https://richstone.io/why-are-there-multiple-names-for-one-method-in-ruby/):

[image]

Ruby does it in favor of developer productivity. Basically, by having aliases you give programmers from different programming languages **and** human languages backgrounds to write code more intuitively.

However, they can also help your code's clarity because some things may have different semantic possibilities like the method `midnight()` can also be expressed as `start_of_day` or `end_of_day`. Those can be more clear depending on the context.

By the way, some programmers use `inject` and `reduce` to differentiate between different semantic situations too.